# how to configure 'send email' in jenkins by proxy

Tags: jenkins, proxy

My Jenkins machine cannot connect to the internet. I want to configure Jenkins to work with a proxy server to send email. The startup parameter is:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=172.16.0.10 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I configured the proxy by appending the below string in 'JAVA_ARGS' setting in '/etc/default/jenkins' and restart the Jenkins server.

```
 -Dhttp.proxyHost=172.16.0.10 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128-Dhttps.proxyHost=172.16.0.10 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the proxy properties on Manage Jenkins > System configurations. In this page you can find "Global Properties" configuration and in this part you have to push the "add" button and put there the HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY properties. These proxy properties should contain the proxy configuration like in the operating system. You can see an example of this configuration in the next image:

[image]

You should replace the properties:

- <$PROTOCOL>         ->  Proxy address protocol (http, https, ...)
- <$USER>             ->  Proxy user authorization (If the proxy require it)
- <$PASS>             ->  Proxy password (If the proxy require it)
- <$PROXY_DNS>        -> Proxy URL or Proxy IP
- <$PORT>             -> Proxy port
- <$DNS1>,<$DNS2>,... -> URL where the proxy don't should be used